# Write blocks of lines from tab delimited file to new file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have many tab delimited files all with 280 lines that I want to break up into standard segments in separate files. I tried doing this as below, and I generate files, but most are empty and others have a very strange format (just random numbers in lots of places that don't make sense). How should I be grabbing these blocks of rows?

```
for histogram in file_names:
with open(histogram,'rt') as tsvin, open(str(histogram)+"_MidA.csv",'w') as MidA, open(str(histogram)+"_ME.csv",'w') as ME, open(str(histogram)+"_ext.csv",'w') as ext, open(str(histogram)+"_EM.csv",'w') as EM, open(str(histogram)+"_MidB.csv",'w') as MidB, open(str(histogram)+"_MF.csv",'w') as MF, open(str(histogram)+"_flex.csv",'w') as flex, open(str(histogram)+"_FM.csv",'w') as FM:
    tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')
    MidA = csv.writer(MidA)
    ME = csv.writer(ME)
    ext = csv.writer(ext)
    EM = csv.writer(EM)
    MidB = csv.writer(MidB)
    MF = csv.writer(MF)
    flex = csv.writer(flex)
    FM = csv.writer(FM)
    for row in tsvin:
        MidA.writerows(row[1:60])
        ME.writerows(row[61:70])
        ext.writerows(row[71:130])
        EM.writerows(row[131:140])
        MidB.writerows(row[141:200])
        MF.writerows(row[201:210])
        flex.writerows(row[211:270])
        FM.writerows(row[271:280])
```

Answer (score 0):

`row` is one row from `tsvin`.
According to [the csv module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html),
`row` is a list of strings then.

So `row[1:60]` refers to columns 2 to 60 of the first line of your file.
Not to some 60 rows, which according to your first sentence *("I have many tab delimited files all with 280 lines")* appears to be what you had in mind.

Comment: I modified it to this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4cf03dfb0a99eb3f9382 which seems to work at first, but it stops working after the third file for some reason (anything after the "ext" segment produces an empty file). I also checked to see if it was finding anything with print, and that was also not working...